# Difference required for compound to be a phenol vs benzene compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

When naming organic compounds, how should one decide whether a compound should be named as a benzene compound, or as a phenol?

For example, the compound [3,4-dihydroxybenzoic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocatechuic_acid) has an -OH group, so why is it not named as a phenol derivative? I feel like I'm missing something here, but none of the numerous sources I've looked at have provided a clear-cut rule to differentiate with.

[image: This image shows the aforementioned compound's displayed formula.]

Comment: Because of [priority rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Order_of_precedence_of_groups)? O:)

Answer (score 5):

In organic nomenclature, when you have a compound with multiple functional groups, you follow the [priority rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Order_of_precedence_of_groups) that have been nicely summed up on Wikipedia:

> When compounds contain more than one functional group, the order of precedence determines which groups are named with prefix or suffix forms. The highest-precedence group takes the suffix, with all others taking the prefix form. However, double and triple bonds only take suffix form (-en and -yn) and are used with other suffixes.

These rules apply to benzene derivatives as well as aliphatic and other cyclic compounds.

Continuing,

> Prefixed substituents are ordered alphabetically (excluding any modifiers such as *di-*, *tri*-, etc.), e.g. chlorofluoromethane, **not** fluorochloromethane. If there are multiple functional groups of the same type, either prefixed or suffixed, the position numbers are ordered numerically (thus ethane-1,2-diol, not ethane-2,1-diol.) The *N* position indicator for amines and amides comes before "1", e.g. $\ce{CH3CH(CH3)CH2NH(CH3)}$ is *N*,2-dimethylpropanamine

Here's a shorter (and quite handy) version of the Wikipedia table <sub>(*shamelessly copied from [masterorganicchemistry.com](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/), I've taken a liking to their color-scheme :-)*)</sub>

> [image]

---

So in the example you've posted:

[image]

You give the carbon atom that has $\ce{-COOH}$ attached to it the *first* locant (because $\ce{-COOH}$ takes precedence over $\ce{-OH}$, according to the priority rules), and you continue numbering *clockwise* so the the two $\ce{-OH}$ groups take locants 3 and 4 respectively ([Lowest set of locants rule](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/WebContent/orgnom/main/difference.html)).

That's how you end up with 3,4-dihydroxybenzoic acid :-)

Comment: The so-called “Table of Functional Group Priorities For Nomenclature” shown on [masterorganicchemistry.com](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/) tries to combine the seniority order of suffixes with prefixes and endings. This can be misleading and result in wrong names. In particular, there is no suffix ‘-ane’, ‘-ene’ or ‘-yne’ (these are endings), and multiple bonds (and all groups that follow in that table) are actually not considered in the seniority order.

Comment: @Loong Hmm, but I can't find a clear enough table (from Google Images) apart from this :/ Every other table's an eyesore. If you know where I can find a better (neat and brief) table  online, I'd appreciate it if you could give me a link. Thanks! O:)